# How hide and show view when scroll page

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote this code, and i hided view

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
```

But if i try show it again, this code cant do it

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
```

Help me please

My code

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        // moved to top
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    } 
    else if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        if tableView.tableHeaderView == nil {
        // moved to bottom
            tableView.tableHeaderView = pre_test_view
        }
    } 
    else {
        // didn't move
    }
}
```

Comment: Your tableHeaderView is not nil, right?

Comment: If it's not nil, I'd recommend setting the tableHeaderView's size using manual layout. They can be super tricky.

Comment: My tableHeaderView is nil

Comment: I mean the `pre_test_view` (you have it named `tableHeaderView` in the first example)

Comment: oh, sorry, yes pre_test_view is nil too

Comment: That's your problem then. You want the pre_test_view to appear but it's actually nil.

Answer (score 0):

So when you initially instantiate the `UITableView` and set the `tableViewHeader` to `nil` you are not really hiding it...so much as initiating the `tableView` without it. What you can do..is call `tableView.reloadData()` after `tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView` and that should probably do it.

Comment: i cant do it, because i try show my view when i scroll bottom my page

Comment: I'm not gonna lie..this is some pretty hacky code...what you can do though..is call tableView.reloadData() then have the tableView's scroll be set to the exact offset point you are at.

Comment: but it reload all tableview and it will looks bad i think